# How to display a message in TestNG report (for passed test cases)

Tags: java, selenium, testng, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

TestNG's default emailable report displays exceptions when a test case is failed or an assert message.

But here I want to add a message to the passed Test cases, say some output value in the TestNG report. To be specific:

```
1. Submit a form in UI.
2. A success message with ID will be displayed.
3. Retrieve that ID using selenium's getText().
4. In the TestNG report, print the above-retrieved ID as "Submitted form ID: {id}".
```

When the user clicks on the report's passed test cases, I want these messages to be displayed.

[image: Passed Test case Message]

Answer (score 3):

You can display the message in Testng report using Reporter.log if the test case got success  then it will print the message as "the value of id is" .

See Below code reference :

```
@Test
public void testCaseEnabling() {
   System.out.println("I'm Not Ready, please don't execute me");

   Assert.assertEquals(actual, expected);

   int id = 10;

   Reporter.log("the value of id is " + id);
}
```

Also: `import org.testng.Reporter;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of Reporter.log and sys.out for that.

I have something like this:

```
import static util.Logging.log;
public class PersonTest  {

   public void validatePersonName() {
      log("Creating new person.");
      Person person = createPerson();

      log("Getting person name.");
      String name = getPersonName(person);
      log("Person name is "+name+".");

      log("Validating person name.");
      validatePersonName(name);
      }

}
```

```
import org.testng.Reporter;
public class LogUtils {

    public static void log(String log) {
        if (!logging) return;

        Reporter.log(log); // This is shown in the report.
        System.out.println("========== " + getTimestamp() + " - " + log); // This is shown in console.
    }

}
```

**And it comes out like this in the report:**
[image]

**And a failed test method would look like (failure cause by testng Assertion):**
[image]

I hope this is what you need.